# DJango call management command asynchronously

Tags: python, django

I have a DJango app and where users upload many images. What I want is to trigger a management command using the `call_command` function from `management` once a new object is created but the problem is I want to do it asynchronously. I don't want to keep the user waiting for the management command to finish. Yes I am aware about third party services like `Celery` but I want to keep it simple. I also know that I can schedule a cron job but the thing is I want the change to reflect instantly. Is there any other way to do so?